# Single Sign On prompting for user when AD Sync enabled for Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We have successfully configured AD Sync between our on-premise domain and Azure AD.  When testing the SSO feature with http://portal.azure.com from a domain joined machine, we only get partial SSO support meaning it prompts for username and does NOT prompt for password (password is sent correctly after specifying user).  After this initial login, it doesn't prompt for either, but my understanding was that it should not prompt for either username or password even on the first attempt (similar to how it works if a computer only Azure AD joined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigated to https://portal.azure.com in a clean browser session, while on the corporate network from a supported browser, then the expected behavior with Azure AD's [Seamless SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso) feature would be:

1. Prompt for username.
2. Do *not* prompt for password.
3. Possibly, prompt for multi-factor authentication.

If you get prompted for a password, then you have not correctly [configured Seamless SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-quick-start).

If this works, and you want to fast-forward past the step where the user is prompted for their username, you need to give the app a hint at what Azure AD tenant you want to sign in to. For example, in the case of the Azure Portal, you could use https://portal.azure.com/contoso.com (for a tenant with verified domain name "contoso.com").